# How to get the date by passing a day in Java

Tags: java

I have 2 days and need to find the whether the given day is within the inputs.

All i have is only days.

For example: if my start time is wednesday ,end time is sunday and current day is thursday, I should check the time span between current week wednesday and next sunday, then the function should return boolean  value yes.

Example 2: if start day is friday ,end day is monday and current day is thursday,i should check within current week friday and upcoming Monday(which is on next week), It should return false in this case.

Comment: Add some code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link, I think you will get the desired stuff easily.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

I mentioning some code, So you can have a idea,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2010-01-12");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-17");
Date dateCurrent = sdf.parse("2010-01-13");

System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));
System.out.println(sdf.format(dateCurrent));

if(date1.before(dateCurrent) && date2.after(dateCurrent)){
    // return true.
}else{
    // return false.
}
```

Comment: did you see the question ? from where will you get the date when the only input is "tuesday" or "wednesday", you could use today's date as the base but that would be a round about way and more complex than need be for this requirement

Answer (score 1):

Declare the days using constants

```
private static final int CONST_SUNDAY = 0;
private static final int CONST_MONDAY = 1;
private static final int CONST_TUESDAY = 2;
private static final int CONST_WEDNESDAY = 3;
private static final int CONST_THURSDAY = 4;
private static final int CONST_FRIDAY = 5;
private static final int CONST_SATURDAY = 6;
```

Then create a method to check the range, the trick is in the endDay shall be in next week if the value is smaller than startDay

```
public static boolean isDayInRange(int startDay, int endDay, int currentDay) {
    if (endDay < startDay) {
        endDay += 7;
    }

    return ((currentDay >= startDay) && (currentDay <= endDay));
}
```

Test the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean result = isDayInRange(CONST_WEDNESDAY, CONST_SUNDAY,
            CONST_THURSDAY);
    boolean result2 = isDayInRange(CONST_FRIDAY, CONST_MONDAY,
            CONST_THURSDAY);
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result2);

}
```

Comment: hi this code goes wrong when i try for                                     boolean result2 = isDayInRange(CONST_FRIDAY, CONST_MONDAY,
       CONST_SUNDAY);                                                  FYI,I need to include the days in inbetween calculation so,I have done a small change like return ((currentDay >= startDay) && (currentDay <= endDay));

Comment: here is the code that works ! <code> public static boolean isDayInRange(int startDay, int endDay, int currentDay) {
     if (endDay < startDay) {
         endDay += 7;
     }
     if(currentDay==0)
     {
      currentDay=7;
     }
     if(currentDay+7==endDay)
     {
      currentDay=7;
     }
     if(currentDay==7 && startDay==0 )
     {
      currentDay=0;
     }
     
     return ((currentDay >= startDay) && (currentDay <= endDay));
 }

Comment: Okay, so you mean that the start and end days shall be included also. Nice, I'll update my answer also. If you don't mind, accept it as an answer :)

Comment: this would be faster way to calculate it then making a date object and then comparingthem

Comment: @tgkprog: besides this is faster, we didn't know what the dates are from the question

Comment: I agree, just surprised to see the other answer has 2 upvotes when it does not answer this and is just a generic date answer!